# HDMI Sound can't be activated

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I try since a while to active my HDMI-Sound in Ubuntu 16.4. But I can't find a way to do so.

```
$aplay -L 

default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=2
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 2
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA Intel HDMI, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3227 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

When I try to switch the sound-output in Pulse-Audio, it shows all HDMI output ports unplugged.

```
pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xd6218000 irq 50"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "160c"
        device.product.name = "Broadwell-U Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Internes Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (priority 5400, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (priority 300, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (priority 300, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Ausgang (priority 5200, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Ausgang (priority 100, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Ausgang (priority 100, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Ausgang (priority 5200, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Ausgang (priority 100, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Ausgang (priority 100, available: unknown)
        off: Aus (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo/#2: Internes Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#3: Monitor of Internes Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 10000 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd621c000 irq 48"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9ca0"
        device.product.name = "Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Internes Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Eingang (priority 60, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Ausgang (priority 6000, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
        off: Aus (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#1: Internes Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Internes Audio Analog Stereo
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#2: Internes Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internes Mikrofon (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-mic: Mikrofon (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Lautsprecher (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Kopfhörer (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

## edit

I have a HP 250 G4 Notebook btw.